# EF query with string as date filtering, how?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have to filter out records that are valid within date ranges.
These date columns are strings in the database ('JAN 01 1900', 'MAY 31 2014').

How can I using Entity Framework 5 (EF5) filter out those records using query method syntax (the problem is that the dates are strings and not DateTime..) ?

Here is a code sample I am working on now:

```
public PostcodeEntry GetPostcodeEntry(string postcode, int huisnummer)
{
    var isEven = (huisnummer % 2) == 0; //tbv performance vd query

    using (ITransactieDataContext transactieDataContext = new TransactieDataContext())
    {
        postcodeEntry = transactieDataContext.PostcodeEntries
            .Where(p => p.Postcode.ToUpper() == postcode.ToUpper())
            .Where(p => p.NummerIsEven == isEven)
            .Where(p => p.ScheidingHoog >= huisnummer)
            .Where(p => p.ScheidingLaag <= huisnummer)
            .Where(SelectValidDateRange())
            .SingleOrDefault();

        return postcodeEntry;
    }
}

private Expression<Func<PostcodeEntry, bool>> SelectValidDateRange()
{
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

    return x => x.StartDate... etc...
}
```

Comment: Why are you storing dates as strings in the database? Any chance you can change that?

Comment: We got an import file (51 MB large, pipe limited) of postcode table entries from our client. We thought to 1 to 1 import it...

Comment: Bad idea. Those are meant to be dates - so import those as dates. Likewise if you've got any numeric fields, import those as numbers. Just because you received the file as text doesn't mean you have to store it in the database as text. Storing data in its most natural form makes it *much*  easier to work with.

Comment: Good point there Jon ;-)

Comment: Agree with Jon's comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jon Skeet already mentioned it correctly that the column type that acts as a Date should be of type DateTime instead of string. After converted this column to DateTime and shifting the 'issue' to a typical source to target conversion (flat file to SQL inserts), I was able to finish my private Expression function correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can't make separate method (`SelectingValidDateRange`) to check dates. But you can use .NET's `Convert.ToDateTime`:

```
.Where(p => Convert.ToDateTime(p.StartDate) < DateTime.Now
         && Convert.ToDateTime(p.EndDate) <= DateTime.Now)
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert.ToDateTime may give an exception while using on entities directly.
Can you try getting records in list first and then using convert method for date comparison.

```
//Get complete list in postcodeEntry first
postcodeEntry = transactieDataContext.PostcodeEntries
                    .Where(p => p.Postcode.ToUpper() == postcode.ToUpper())
                    .Where(p => p.NummerIsEven == isEven)
                    .Where(p => p.ScheidingHoog >= huisnummer)
                    .Where(p => p.ScheidingLaag <= huisnummer).ToList()

//Then add Convert.ToDateTime() filter on list
var requiredResult = postcodeEntry.where(p=> Convert.ToDateTime(p.StratDate) < DateTime.Now && Convert.ToDateTime(p.EndDate) > DateTime.Now).SingleOrDefault();
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

```
.Where(x =>{
string[] strDates = x.DateFieldHere.Split(",");
DateTime d1,d2;
if(DateTime.TryParse(strDates[0], out d1) 
&& DateTime.TryParse(strDates[1], out d2))
{ 
  return d1>= parameterHere1 && d2 <= parameterHere2;
}
return false; }).SingleorDefault();
```